# How can I fix for loop to other things

Tags: python, discord.py

Currently I have set a `for loop` which retrieves data from the database for every row.
I need to use run a while loop, however it would not run as the for loop finishes once after it has retrieved database data. In result, this stops the rest of my `While true` loop to await for user response

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM maincores WHERE set_status = 1")
rows = c.fetchall()
for v in rows:
        # skip
        while True:
               #skip
```

I have tried using a global variable to store the database data then return the loop, all resulting in a fail.
How can I get sqlite3 database information without using for loop?

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you trying to convert your for loop to a while loop? what have you tried, what results did you get? [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Give a simple example with 3-5 rows of data, in order to understand the problem more precisely.

Comment: Can you tell me your telegram or discord or etc ? I want to ask there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on the problem, but I think you might want to use a generator so that you throttle your intake of information with your loop.  So, you could do a function like:

```
def getDBdata():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM maincores WHERE set_status = 1")
    rows = c.fetchall()
    for v in rows:
        yield(v) #just returns one result at a time ...

x = True
data = getDBdata()
while x is True:
    do something with data
    if <condition>:
        next(data) #get the next row of data
    else:
        x = False
```

So, now you are controlling the data flow from your DB so that you don't exhaust your while loop as a condition of the data flow.

My apologies if I'm not answering the question your asking, but I hope this helps.